# Communicating with the GUI

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a small application, written in C#. The GUI is composed in XAML/WPF.
There's nothing fancy about it. A user enters some settings, presses a button and waits for stuff to happen. However as the application has grown alot in the past weeks, the code is getting terrible. Really terrible. Fixups in places I feel they don't belong. It's slowly becoming a maintainability hell. And the application will still grow a lot in the near future.

I would very much like to refactor this in to more mature, maintainable code. If not for anything than to how to code and design an application better.

Since the user has no real way of knowing stuff is actually happening, I'm planning to add a status bar displaying some important stuff, so the user at least has some idea what's happening.

Now, how should I go about doing this. My gui instantiates some object, which in turn instantiate other objects. I could just pass a reference to the gui-window through the application, but that's just dirty. What do you guys recommend?

I've been looking into MVVM for a bit, but I'm not sure if that's what I need. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For sure you need MVVM to put everything in order but what you're facing is the common learning process.

Read as much as you can about MVVM and OOP (focus on OOP if you don't master it a lot) and work with it until you feel REALLY comfortable with the code you wrote (you probably need some years to get to that level).

You have an amazing path in front of you.

Answer (score 1):

MVVM is indeed one way to structure your code for better maintainability.  I've been using it now for a while and it's a pretty natural, low impedance way to put together some code that has some built in separation of concerns.

Also note that you can make MVVM ugly too.  It still comes down to following some decent practices at the code level.

Keep iterating over the code until it feels like something that you're not afraid to have someone else look at.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MVVM is a way to the solution.

In general, you might think of the [Observer pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternObserver.aspx) and events. It helps you enabling any object to notify a GUI they do not know.

Answer (score 0):

You could use MVVM to solve coupling issues yes.

With the appropriate data and Binding, you can have the state stay in your heavy lifting class.

You can use either a bool that just represents whether it is currently working, or add a string that describe the state, or a nullable type for result that you can test with a converter, etc...

In MVVM Light - http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/ - you also have a Messenger tool that would solve the problem in another way. You'd broadcast the status change from the heavy lifter, without caring who's listening (decoupling). This pattern has several names and variants (observer, subscribe, signal, ...)